# Multiple orderByChild filter in firebase database query

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I want to filter data from firebase database in angular 4 application. I need to apply two filters.

1. Fetch all onLine users
2. Fetch all not playing users

I read few articles that, We cannot add two orderByChild critearea in query. So I used map function as below,

```
users: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
public DB:
AngularFireDatabase;

constructor(private router: Router, private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
  this.DB = db;
}
showPeopleList() {

  this.users = <FirebaseListObservable<any>>this.DB.list('/users',
  {
    query: {
      orderByChild: 'isOnline',
      equalTo: true,
      limitToLast: 20
    }
  }).map((items)=> { 
    let filteredUser: any[];
    for (let item of items) {
      if(items.isPlaying == false){
        filteredUser.push(item);
      }
    }
    return filteredUser;
});



}
```

In above code, in  map function, I am getting all Online users, but I am not able to filter data based on Playing field.
What changes do I need t make to get this done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just use the `.filter` function for this.

```
.filter(item => item.isPlaying === false)
```

In your above code you have a spelling error which also might cause your current function not to work. Notice the `s` in after `items` in your `if` statement.

```
 if(items.isPlaying == false){
        filteredUser.push(item);
 }
```

Comment: Have one question. In my code, isPlaying filter will work on only 20 records or it will work on all records in firebase and then return total 20 rows ? If it works on 20 records only, then there may be chance that all 20 are isPlaying === true, and I get nothing :(